# How to use googl uri field to solve audio file more than 1 minute in google SpeechRecognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

In the website of SpeechRecognition of google as the following

https://cloud.google.com/speech/quotas

it was taught that if the audio file more than one min, it should be used the uri field to solve the problmes.

I upload a file in google cloud storage with bucket as speechrecognitionelong

and file name as test.wav

So i think the uri name for this file should be gs://speechrecognitionelong/test.wav

I use the following code but it does not work

```
import speech_recognition as sr

AUDIO_FILE = "gs://speechrecognitionelong/test.wav" r = sr.Recognizer() with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file

r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
```

Did I misunderstand the uri filed or my code was wrong?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same issue. Not sure how to specify the gs Uri location to the wave file. Can u @Elong-chen provide a copy of your sample python code?